# How to use COUNT and GROUP BY (or similar alternative) when selecing transformed columns

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have a table column with categories and I would like to decrease the number of categories. The following code should make it clear:

```
 SELECT 
     CASE 
        WHEN category_ IN ('cat1', 'cat2') 
           THEN category_ 
           ELSE 'other' 
     END
 FROM 
     mytable
```

Now suppose I want to count how many observations there is in each of the three new categories (cat1, cat2 and other). How can I do that without subqueries?

The desired output should be something like

```
 category_      cnt
 ----------------------------
 cat1           (some number)
 cat2           (some number)
 other          (some number)
```

I have tried something like

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN category_ IN ('cat1', 'cat2') 
          THEN category_  
          ELSE 'other' 
    END AS category_new,
    COUNT (CASE WHEN category_ IN ('cat1', 'cat2') THEN category_ ELSE 'other' END)
FROM 
    mytable
GROUP BY 
    (CASE WHEN category_ IN ('cat1', 'cat2') THEN category_  ELSE 'other' END)
```

I am using TOAD and an Oracle database

Comment: Do you have an issue with your query?  It looks basically correct.

Answer (score 1):

You code should work, but it can be simplified to:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN category_ IN ('cat1', 'cat2') THEN category_ ELSE 'other' END) AS category_new,
       COUN (*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN category_ IN ('cat1', 'cat2') THEN category_  ELSE 'other' END);
```

Comment: I didn't what h*ll I was thinking. hmmm. But thanks it works.

Comment: OK, I think it was because I used `GROUP BY category_new)` in the last line :)

Comment: Another problem is that it takes a lot of time to run compared to the one without transformation.... Wonder why.

Comment: @k.dkhk . . . Presumably because an index can be used without the transformation.